# Positioning div relative to slider image

Tags: css, revolution-slider

I am unable to make a revolution slider layer stay put when resizing the main window. The layer's position jumps all over the place.

You can see the desired effect here: http://52.55.50.79/

The hotspots more or less stay in the same place when screen is resized.

However, the same hotspot here: http://www.jardindelzen.com/ (See 4th slide on main homepage slider), jumps all over the place when screen is resized.

The only difference between these is that in the first case the hotspots are on top of an image, while in the second case the hotspots are on top of an image as a layer of a revolution slider.

No amount of fiddling with the layer's responsive settings in the slider revolution settings panel fixes the issue.

[image: Correct - size 1]

[image: Correct - size 2]

[image: Incorrect - size 1]

[image: Incorrect - size 2]

Comment: Does Revolution Slider allow you to input percentage positions? Those are always favorable to pixel positions.

Comment: I thought of that too. Unfortunately no. Each time I enter a number plus the percentage into their settings it gets switched into px.